# How to find the first link on the page containing this text?

Tags: xpath

If I have two links:

```
<div class="abc">
  <a id="def1" href="/definitely">Definitely 1</a>
  <a id="def2" href="/definitely">Definitely 2</a>    
</div>
```

And I want to identify the first (`def1`), I thought this would work:

```
var linkXPath = "//div[@class='abc']//a[contains(@href,'def')][1]";
```

But it doesn't seem to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just tested. Your expression works.

Comment: In what language? If you are working in .NET the problem might be incorrect configuration of namespaces in the XML document and the XPath processor.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're working with well-formed XML?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation, and a solution. :)

Comment: It's not zero based index?

Answer (score 4):

**It is a FAQ** why

```
//someName[1]
```

doesn't select the first element of `//someName`.

Looking at **[the definition of the `//` abbreviation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)**, **one would realize that in fact**

```
//someName[1]
```

**is equivalent to**:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/someName[1]
```

and this selects every `someName` element that is the first `someName` child of its parent node.

**Thus, if there are two or more `someName` elements that are the first `someName` child of their parent, all of them are selected.**

**Solution**:

Instead of

```
//someName[1]
```

**use**:

```
(//someName)[1]
```

**So, in your particular case use**:

```
(//div[@class='abc']//a[contains(@href,'def')]) [1]
```

**Apart from this**, none of the above expressions would select any node, if in the actual XML document a default namespace was specified. Selecting nodes in a document with a default namespace is the biggest XPath FAQ. To find the solution just search for "default namespace" in this SO tag and anywhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath expression selects the first `a` element (with the right href) of *every* `div` (that has the right class) that contains one. So if there were two `div`s that matched, each with multiple `a` elements that matched, you'd get a reault set containing two elements -- the first `a` in the first `div`, and the first `a` in the second `div`.

To select just the first element of the entire result set, use parentheses like so:

```
(//div[@class='abc']//a[contains(@href,'def')])[1]
```

Other than that, your expression works fine for me (tested [here](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm)).